# quasar can't build asset folder

Tags: vue.js, quasar

My project has `static` folder and `asset` folder. 
I use  `quasar dev` to build project and the building project is stored in `dist` folder. But in the `dist` folder, it only has `static` folder, it doesn't has `asset` folder.
How can I let `asset` be packaged in `dist` folder?

Answer (score 1):

I also had some struggle working with these two directories in Quasar. So I was very happy when I found [this page](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/cli-documentation/handling-assets#Static-Assets---%2Fsrc%2Fstatics) in the documentation. The difference between `assets` and `statics` is described as follows:

> Assets vs Statics
>
> Files in the “assets” folder are only included in your build if they have a 
>   literal reference in one of your Vue files. Every file and folder from the > “statics” folder are copied into your production build as-is, no matter what.

So I guess that you currently do not use any of the files inside the `assets` directory in at least one of your components.

Example: One possible way to make `logo.png` be part of the `dist` folder is to use the asset in a Vue component like this (also taken from the docs): `<img src="~assets/logo.png">`. Afterwards run `quasar build` and check the output in your `dist` folder. Good luck!